# Angular 2 missing module

Tags: angular

I crated the sample app using Augular CLI command. now trying to test the getting started application from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html# sample code.

when I add these lines

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
```

its giving the below error message.

```
Module '"c:/shared/testngproj/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'NgModule'.
import NgModule
```

How can import these three modules?

Here is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "testngproj",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "forms-angular": "^0.7.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.10",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.20",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "0.5.5",
    "tslint": "3.11.0",
    "typescript": "1.8.10",
    "typings": "1.3.1"
  }
}
```

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NgModule` was introduced in Angular 2 RC5, which was released a couple days ago, and the Angular documentation has since been updated to reflect the change.

Your package.json still references RC4 (2.0.0-rc.4), which doesn't have `NgModule`. You will need to upgrade to RC5 (2.0.0-rc.5) to successfully follow the tutorial.

Comment: What about `FormsModule`? I cloned the [heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html) source from github(which uses RC4) and then updated to RC5. Not sure what version the tutorial docs use. Compiler tells me can't find `FormsModule` in `forms`. I checked the `.d.ts` files and agree with it. `FormsModule` is just not there. Thanks.

Comment: @潘俊杰: You should post a new question.